# Can't assign type Headers

Tags: angular, typescript

```
Can't assign type Headers.
No overload matches this call.
   The last reload returned the following error.
     Type 'Headers' cannot be assigned to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; } | undefined".
       Type 'Headers' cannot be assigned to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[; }'.
         Type 'Headers' is missing an index signature for type 'string'.
```

```
import { HttpClient,} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({

  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {

  constructor(

    private http :  HttpClient 
  
  ) { }

  regidterUser(user: any) {

    let headers = new Headers()

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/account/reg', user, 

    {headers: headers})
  }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, place code in `code` blocks properly.

Comment: HttpHeaders <> Headers

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the headers with an object, as follows:

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  })
};



.....

return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/account/reg', user, httpOptions)
```

After that you can use the append function to append a http option.

Answer (score 0):

HttpHeaders is immutable, those methods always return a new copy with the added headers , this will work

```
headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
```